# Azure DevOps agent running an application with a dialog box

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, teststand

I am trying to run National Instruments TestStand [Sequence Analyzer](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370052AA-01/tsref/infotopics/sequence_analyzer/) as part of a build in Azure DevOps using a Python script. Agent is running as a service.

```
import subprocess
command = '"%teststand%\Bin\AnalyzerApp.exe" MyAnalyzerProject.tsaproj /analyze /report /save /quit'
exit_code = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
print(exit_code) # returns the exit status
```

It works when I run it manually, but fails when agent tries to run it:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
   at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp)
   at AnalyzerApp.e.a(String A_0, String A_1)
   at NationalInstruments.TestStand.Utility.LaunchTestStandApplicationInNewDomain.HandleLaunchProtectedException(Exception e, String applicationName, DisplayErrorMessageDelegate displayErrorMessage)
   at NationalInstruments.TestStand.Utility.LaunchTestStandApplicationInNewDomain.LaunchProtectedReturnCode(MainEntryPointDelegateWithArgsReturnCode entryPoint, String[] args, String applicationName, DisplayErrorMessageDelegate displayErrorMessage, Boolean parseArgs)
   at AnalyzerApp.e.b(String[] A_0)
```

I tried running it using cmd first, but depending on Agent service user it either gets stuck or throws an error -532462766 (0xE0434352) and writes a similar entry to event log.

There is no need for user interaction: normally dialog opens and closes when analysis is done. I am after the exit code and report file that it creates. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by running the agent interactively instead of as a service. It seems that the only dis-benefit of running interactively is a need for auto logon and associated security risk.
More about service vs interactive can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service).

Comment: That's right. The Hosted Agents also run interactively. You can also add a additional Build Stage and have that use the Hosted Agent in case you can get your interactive tool installed on it.